# How to use opencv ann to evaluate a function output

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, neural-network

Can I compute the function `f(x) = sqr(x)` using `opencv` `ANN` ?
I need to train my ann by using set of integers and their square values.

I need to get squared value of a integer as output from `ann model`.

If we can do that using opencv `ann`, what will be the number input neurons, output neurons and how to specify the classes etc.. ??

Answer (score 0):

You mention class specification, but I don't think that this is a class categorization problem. I think it would be better to treat the input as X, and the output as sqr(X). Then this becomes a general function approximation problem.

There is an issue with this particular problem however. Neural networks aren't well suited for functions with unbounded input/output. The output of a neural network is usually limited to the range of its activation function, and the input value is usually scaled to some reasonable range. Assuming you are using the default activation (symmetrical sigmoid), your output is limited to (-1, 1). If you have a limited range of integers you want to use, you can still do this, but you'll have to scale the inputs and outputs accordingly.

If you use this method, there will be one input node, and one output node, corresponding to the scaled versions of X and sqr(X) respectively. OpenCV will try to take care of scaling for you automatically. It's probably best for you to trust this, UNLESS you are planning on providing multiple different sets of training data. The different sets may have different distributions, hence a different scale.